# How to validate url in php to avoid continue .. and ::

Tags: url, web

How to validate url in php to avoid continue .. and  :: 
For ex:
http::/www.gmail.com
or
http://www.gmail.com
or
http://www.gmail.com.....

Comment: I haven't get solution for url validation. Please if anyone has solution then please share it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the PHP tag for your question if you are looking for an answer PHP related.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP filter:

```
$url = "http://google.com";
if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
  echo "URL is OK";
}
else {
  echo "URL is invalid";
}
```